# React : TypeError: items.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unique

I am getting this error [TypeError: items.map is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kNq2.png) while using get unique function in react. Please anyone can help me out.
Thank you

```
import React from 'react';
import Hero from "../components/Hero";
import Banner from "../components/Banner";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import RoomContainer from "../components/RoomContainer";

const getUnique = (items,value)=>{
    return [...new Set(items.map(item => item[value]))];
};

function RoomFilter(rooms) {
  const context = useContext(RoomContext);
  const { handleChange, type } = context;
  //get unique types

  let types = getUnique(rooms, 'type');
  //add all
  types = ['all', ...types];
  //map to jsx
  types = types.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <option value={item} key={index}>
        {item}
      </option>
    );

  });

  return (
    <section className="filter-container">
      <Title title="search rooms" />
      <form className="filter-form">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="type">Room Type</label>
          <select name="type" id="type" value={type} className="form-control" onChange={handleChange}>{types}</select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}

export default RoomFilter;
```

Comment: const getUnique = (items,value)=>{
    return [...new Set(items.map(item => (item[value])))];
};
function RoomFilter(rooms) {
    const context = useContext(RoomContext);
    const {
        handleChange,type,capacity,price,minPrice,maxPrice,minSize,maxSize,breakfast,  pets} = context;
    
    let types = getUnique(rooms,"type");
    
    types = ["all", ...types];
    //map to jsx
    types = types.map((item, index)=>{
        return (
            <option value={item} key={index}>
                {item}
            </option>
        );

    }); Here is my Code

Comment: This just means that `rooms` is not a valid list. If you reformat your code and display more of it, it will be easier for us to help. Don't stick code into a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have uploaded the code .plz kindly look after it

Comment: I have uploaded my "RoomFilter" full code there. plz, check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to a react functional component is it's `props`.

However your code is describing a property of props.

```js
function RoomFilter(rooms) {
```

You can fix this with destructuring either in the argument or later as a const.

```js
function RoomFilter({ rooms }) {
```

or

```js
function RoomFilter(props) {
  const { rooms } = props;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
now it's working fine :)

Comment: Holy crap! I dont know who are you? But I pretty sure you're my personal angel! Thank you so much Mr. Ed Knowels. Two days straight i cant solve this TypeError. Again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass in `getUnique` function argument `rooms`, which *is not an array*. You need to check where you pass this property to `RoomFilter`. In most situation it's related with that the start value of some state variables is *undefined* instead of **[]** (how in this case). But, if you need more help, you should show more code :)

Comment: I have uploaded my "RoomFilter" full code there. plz, check that

Answer (score 0):

Item.map is not a function because you are trying to fill [a new Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with values and a set.add(value) takes a function which returns a object that can return a value to be added with add(value).